# the menu of the network does not display my second website

Tags: multisite, admin-menu, network-admin

I have a problem that is not referenced anywhere.
In the toolbar, the menu of the network does not display my second website, while it is active and appears in the list of the sites in the network.
I checked the wp-config and .htaccess files and I did not error. I followed step by step the stages of the codex.

Comment: Did you set up the second site with a different administrator email address? The **My Sites** menu will only show sites that have your email address as the primary administrator, even if you're a Super Admin. To see all the sites on a network, go to the **Network Admin » Sites** page (usually `[your URL]/wp-admin/network/sites.php`).

Comment: Thanks, it could be the solution because I had a different email address for the second website. But even after correcting the email address the problem is not resolved

Comment: Resolved : the second website created must be managed by the same administrator or  more exactly super-admin. For that I must do that : Network Admin > Sites > Click Edit on a specific site > Users tab > Add Existing User -> and choose "id" of admin.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. If you'd like, you can answer your own question, then accept the answer once you're able to. That way, your answer might be able to help others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved : the second website created must be managed by the same administrator or more exactly super-admin. For that I must do that : Network Admin > Sites > Click Edit on a specific site > Users tab > Add Existing User -> and choose "id" of admin.